# Angular2 style binding not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am starting with Angular2 and I got stuck on a following simple style setting which I don't know why doesn't work (following https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings)

What is wrong?

(I tried also [style.background-image] and [style.background.image] and using a component method to construct the "url(...)" string)

Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'front-page',
    template: `<div [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + headerImage + ')'" [title]="title">&nbsp;</div>`
})
export class FrontPageComponent {
    headerImage = "http://example.com/image.jpg"
    title = "test"
}
```

Result:

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>

  <body>
    <app-component>
      <front-page>
        <div title="test">
          &nbsp;
        </div>
      </front-page>
    </app-component>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm quite sure its a duplicate. If not, add a comment to get it reopened.

Comment: Despite trying I didn't find this one. It seems as a duplicate. Sorry.